# FileUpload: DeferredFileOutputStream class not found?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm using apache FileUpload to handle a.. file upload. I'm using it with jetty. The servlet sees the multipart request, but throws a NoClassDefFoundError exception upon execution:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
  throws ServletException, IOException 
{
  boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
  if (isMultipart) {
    try {
      FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

      List items = upload.parseRequest(req); //  exception
      ...
```

throws:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
   at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
```

caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream
```

Is there an additional jar we need to include besides commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar?

My goal is to just upload a single file and write it to disk.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add [CommonsIO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to the classpath. Commons File Upload is dependent on it.

Comment: maven repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io

Answer (score 4):

Add the below dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: To see another versions access link: https://mvnrepository.com/