# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons

I am getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream` when tring to upload a file to my server runnning on localhost. This is the servlet I am using:

```
@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "~/EclipseProjects/DocSearch/uploads";

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public UploadServlet() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            for(FileItem item: multiparts) {
                if(!item.isFormField()) {
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                }
            }
            request.setAttribute("message", "File uploaded successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "File upload failed due to: " + ex);
        }
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("message", "Sorry this servlet only handles file upload requests");
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

}
```

I have already added commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder. I have tried creating a new server and running the project on it, tried re-downloading the jar file from different sources, but none of them seems to solve my problem.

Note:

I have already gone through:

- [How to solve this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154252/how-to-solve-this-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-io-output-d)
- [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091687/javax-servlet-servletexception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commo)
- [FileUpload: DeferredFileOutputStream class not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342241/fileupload-deferredfileoutputstream-class-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include  `commons-fileupload.jar`  into your project dependency library folder.

Get `commons-fileupload.jar` from official website – http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi or from maven web site:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1

if you use maven add this dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used maven build for this particular project but I have tried adding the jar in the java build path in the project properties.

Comment: @shyam download the jar from appache web site and add it in you project build pth.

Comment: Yes. That did the trick. I'll accept your answer if you edit out the link you have given. (It's commons-fileupload not commons-io). Still curious to why the previous jars didn't work though. I downloaded it from maven central actually.